# Navigator not working if sliding-menu is added to page Onsen UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

I recently added a sliding-menu to one of my PhoneGap mobile apps, and now all the page-changes that depended on the myNavigator.ResetToPage('htmlpage.html') function stopped working.

The sliding menu hosts only a couple of auxiliary views that are not that important.

Here's a sketch of the index.html file

```
<ons-sliding-menu main-page="main.html" menu-page="menu.html" side="left" max-slide-distance="250px" var="menu">
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="menu.setMainPage('main.html', {closeMenu: true})">
      Home
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="menu.setMainPage('my_stuff.html', {closeMenu: true})">
      My Stuff
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-template>


<ons-template id="main.html">
    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
        <ons-page ng-controller="AppController" id="main">
            <ons-tabbar>
                <ons-tab active="true" page="page1.html">
                    <div class="tab">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-calendar" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
                        <div class="tab-label">Page 1</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-tab>
                <ons-tab page="page2.html">
                    <div class="tab">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-checkmark" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
                        <div class="tab-label">Page 2</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-tab>
                <ons-tab page="settings.html">
                    <div class="tab">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a" class="tab-icon"></ons-icon>
                        <div class="tab-label">Settings</div>
                    </div>
                </ons-tab>
            </ons-tabbar>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
</ons-template>


<ons-template id="settings.html">
    <ons-page id="settings">
        <ons-toolbar style="background-color:#222;">
            <div class="center" style="color: white">Settings</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        A HELP BUTTON WITH ng-click="navigateHelp()"
        AN ABOUT BUTTON WITH ng-click="navigateAbout()"
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Is there any connection between the sliding-menu and the navigator, that made the navigator to stop working?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `setMainPage`you are changing `ons-sliding-menu`'s content. `ons-navigator` is part of the content that you change, so if you load `settings.html` page with `setMainPage` you won't have navigator there (it's only inside `main.html`).

Stop using `menu.setMainPage` and use always `ons-navigator` methods. The equivalent would be `myNavigator.resetToPage(...)`:

```
<ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="myNavigator.resetToPage('main.html'); menu.close();">
      Home
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="myNavigator.resetToPage('my_stuff.html'); menu.close();">
      My Stuff
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-template>
```

This way you maintain the menu content, i.e. the navigator, and only change navigator's content.

Comment: This only works, if I first click on the HOME button in the menu.
So if I load up the app, go to the Settings page directly, and try to click on the ABOUT / HELP buttons, they are not working. But if I use the sliding-menu, to navigate to the Home page (from the Home page...weird) then afterwards it will work. After that, every page navigation will work correctly...

Comment: Also I'm getting this error: You can not supply no "ons-page" element to "ons-navigator". when using myNavigator.resetToPage('main.html')

Comment: Yes, because `main.html` contains the actual navigator, not a page. Put the `ons-navigator` in  `navigator.html` and load it from the sliding menu with `main-page="navigator.html"` attribute. Then make `main.html` to contain only the `ons-page` without the navigator component. Navigator should have `page="main.html"` attribute.